# Parse variable data in onclicklistener through intent

Tags: java, android

Okay, so I have a buttonarray which I all instansiate with a for loop. Each button gets an ID aswell as an onclicklistener. The onclicklistener opens a new intent (a new activity which is the same for all buttons) and depending on the ID of the button pressed, the new activity should show a certain pdf file.

The problem is that the last number in my array gets parsed to the new intent. So all buttons get the same ID instead of increase from 0 to 45.

Sheetmusiclist.java (mainactivity):

```
Button sheetsButtons[];
int id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheetsmusiclist);
    sheetsButtons = new Button[46];

    for(int i=0;i<46;i++){
        id = i;
        sheetsButtons[i] = new Button(this);
        sheetsButtons[i].setId(i);

        View.OnClickListener mThisButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SheetMusicList.this, SheetMusic.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intent);}};

        sheetsButtons[i].setOnClickListener(mThisButtonListener);
    }}
```

Then in the next activity (Sheetmusic.java) I recall the intent and get the ID. Then depending on the ID I show a pdf file. But in all cases the last ID in the array is shown: 45.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheetmusic);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
    if(bd != null){
        id = (int) bd.get("id"); //ID here is always 45
    }

//a switch here with id -> pdf file name
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `intent.putExtra("id", v.getId());` instead of `intent.putExtra("id", id);`.

At the moment you are saving your *id* variable as global for that class and you are assigning an *i* to it. After all the `Button` creations are done and when you click on the `Button` your *id* variable remains as the last *i* from your `for` loop, that is why you always get "last" elements in your intent.

By doing it with `v.getId();` you get an id of clicked Button, which you assign as an *i* during creation process, so all the *ids* of `Buttons` are different.

---

Hope this helps. Good luck :)